# asp net javascript Cache clear

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a website that i did some time ago now they request some new features and i did some changes in some javascript files, but when i publish the clients that use the IE have problems with cache so in they browser they have old version of javascript. How can i clear the client cache so when they visit website they use latest javascript files that i modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you refer your javascript file append a version number also to the end of the file as a query string. Something like

```
<script src="yourjsfile?version=1.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will refer to a new url which won't be present in the cache and the browser will download the latest file.

Comment: Suppose, it would be better to use timespan instead of version number here

Comment: No, need to use timespan. Using timespan will always load the file from server. Here when the file is changed then only the new file has to be downloaded.

Comment: Yep, sure. The only thing I wanted to mention is not to forget to change version query parameter (timespan will do it automatically but as you mentioned above the file will be always load from server).